# Remove prefix pattern from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have to work with some files/folders which can contain certain prefixes. For example, a file name could be

> 1.2.0 MyDocfile.doc
>   1.1.2.3 Anotherfile.txt

I want to be able to remove the prefix and the space after that (1.2.0, 1.1.2.3) and just take the actual file name.
What is the best way to do this ? Regular expressions ?

Can someone please give an example?

Comment: You must clarify the "can contain" part. Does that mean that some files might not have this prefix? Can the "actual file name" contain spaces?

Comment: I believe all the files will have some prefix like this. And the actual file name can/will contain spaces in most cases. 
I haven't tried anything before posting, just can't get any thoughts. 

The Regex.Replace(name, @"^[\d.]* ",  ""); is working great. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var formattedName = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

In case of optional prefix you need regex:

```
var formattedName = Regex.Replace(name, @"^[\d.]* ",  "");
```

To get all file names formatted:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\d.]* ");
IEnumerable<string> formattedNames = names.Select(f => regex.Replace(f, ""));
```

Comment: You wrote it without VS too, you can't declare and use it at the same time.

Comment: @PhiLho if prefix is missing, then file name will stay unchanged. Actually I'd even used `^[\d.]*\s+` to remove more than one space between prefix and name

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, I was still thinking in terms of capture, while you do a replace. Sorry. :-)

Comment: Filenames can contain embedded spaces and you are still removing a leading space or number so I would suggest "^([\d]+.)+\s+" as a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

`"^[\\d.]* ?(.*)$"` should give you the actual file name in the capture.

That's a generic answer as I don't know C#.

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(FileName, @"^[\d.]* ?(.*)$");

Comment: Good, assuming "123", "..." and "..1.3" are valid prefixes to be ignored.  Depends on how crap the input is, ofc

Comment: some how this particular regular expression didn't give me the result. I was always getting an empty string with Regex.match

Comment: @CrazyFrog, are you using a verbatim string?  If you are, you need to drop one of the backslashes: `@"^[\d.]* ?(.*)$"`

Comment: Yes, I doubled the backslash because that's what we do in Java, but @MikedeKlerk gave a correct solution (I suppose... but I trust it). The solution you elected is probably better anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

If there isn't a space in the name, it will just return the name. This avoids the need for any Regular Expressions.

Comment: "which *can* contain certain prefixes". If the file hasn't such prefix, but has spaces in the name, it needs more logic...

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions would be the best solution. If the prefix is in a consistent format as you described, the following should cut it:

```
filenames.RemoveAll(filename => Regex.IsMatch(filename, @"^([\d\.]+ )"));
```

This is a more complete example:

```
var filenames = new List<string> { "1.2.0 MyDocfile.doc", "1.1.2.3 Anotherfile.txt", "Otherfile.doc", " strange_file_name.docx" };
filenames.RemoveAll(filename => Regex.IsMatch(filename, @"^([\d\.]+ )"));    
filenames.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This will print "Otherfile.doc" and " strange_file_name.docx". If you want to remove the last file as well (beginning with a space) use the following pattern `^([\d\.]* )`.

*Update: I added the caret '^' to indicate that it should match the beginning of the string.*